# Search for consecutive words from a string in a hashtable

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, contains, string-comparison

I have a hash map, the key value is a word and the second value is the subject to that word.

Some key values examples are:

```
Good, Bad, Not Good, Very Good

HashMap<String, String> subjectMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I also have a bunch of Strings that I need to check against this. So if I have a String that says "This is not good" I want to return the subject as a negative review. What I am doing now is going through the String word by word but it won't pick up multiple word indexes.

Is there an efficient way to search through a String for a word in a hashmap that isn't only one word at a time?

Comment: iterate the map entries and check if the string `contain()`s the key value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code only has the flaw to print 2 results (

```
Good
Not Good
```

), because the string contains both. You will have to change the key's to be totally unique in this approach, otherwise you can't be certain

```
String s = "This is not good";
HashMap<String, String> subjectMap = new HashMap<>();
subjectMap.put("Good", "");
subjectMap.put("Bad", "");
subjectMap.put("Not Good", "");
subjectMap.put("Very Good", "");

for (String str : subjectMap.keySet()) {
    if (s.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean now from trying things out. What approach would you recommend?

Comment: Depends on where the input comes from and whether the input is always the same or if it can be different